# How to automatically run JBoss app on startup, using RedHat

Tags: java, jboss, startup, redhat

Not too long ago, I installed a java web application on a Red Hat server running JBOSS.

After a recent reboot, I realized that the site did not start up automatically when the machine was booted.

Is there an easy way to ensure that this happens?  There are shell scripts to start and stop the application, something like :

```
/opt/myApp/StartMyApp.sh
/opt/MyApp/StopMyApp.sh
```

I have been reading about Redhat Run Levels, (etc/rc.d), but it seems too complicated for what I need to do - just run the shell script after booting.

Making it a Windows service is quite easy, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do the equivalent with Redhat.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been covered at

http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/startjbossonbootwithlinux

edit: redhat page on that: http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Application_Stack/2.2/html/Release_Notes/sn-usingjbossas.html

Comment: I prefered the Jboss article.  Just have to test it out now.